# line chart unable to draw with month on x axis

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I am unable to draw line chart in months on x axis when I am using date field from the json data then its coming while using month from that date it's not drawing and console also not showing any error, I have given here fiddle for that scenario with json data  http://jsfiddle.net/6zrMc/7

```
data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.date =parseDate(d.date);  
    d.close = +d.close;
});
var valueline = d3.svg.line()
.x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
.y(function(d) { return y(d.close); });    
x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));
y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.close; })]);
```

this code is working fine but which I have shown in fiddle that is not working only with month type
please anyone suggest me on this.

Answer (score 0):

You use `d.activemonth` in your x-scale (which is a times-scale). So `d.activemonth` needs to be a date-object. The way `parseMonth` is defined (without `.parse`) it parses a date-object to string. So

```
parseMonth(new Date(d.date))
```

Will return the string `Oct` and `x(d.activemonth)` will be `x('Oct')` which is invalid since x only takes date-objects. The solution is to change

```
d.activemonth = parseMonth(new Date(d.date));
```

to a valid date-object, for example

```
 d.activemonth = new Date(d.date);
```

(Which will be the same as `d.date`).

Comment: I didn't understand please can you correct in fiddle so I can have clear Idea on it

Comment: fine I understood this one and I have tried also but actually result is like wed thu , which I dont want, It should be only month names on x axis and count that's y I asked u again

Comment: bro 1 last thing when I have more than one entry with same month how can i some up because it is always re-writing over the same value like in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/6zrMc/15/

Comment: whatever u have given its not between month and count , its between date and count, I want to draw graph between month and count so this one is not the right solution http://jsfiddle.net/6zrMc/12/